# TripleDES IV for C#?

Tags: c#, encryption, vector, initialization

So when I say something like:

```
TripleDES tripledes = TripleDES.Create();
Rfc2898DeriveBytes pdb = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(password, plain);
tripledes.Key = pdb.GetBytes(16);
tripledes.IV = pdb.GetBytes(16);
```

I get an error. The error used to be on the key, but its been fixed (I think - unless you spot something wrong). However, the error occurs when I set the IV:

```
tripledes.IV = pdb.GetBytes(16);
```

It says that its not a valid initialization vector.

How do I fix it?

Comment: "not a valid initialization vector" is vague. What is the exact exception you're getting?

Comment: Remember that AES is more efficient than Tripple DES.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The block size for TripleDES is 64 bits. You are trying to set 128 bits.

This should work:

```
tripledes.IV = pdb.GetBytes(8);
```

Comment: For reference you can check your key size with ValidKeySize (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.symmetricalgorithm.validkeysize)

Comment: Thanks, this seems to work for me. -- Just for future reference, how exactly do you determine the block size for an algorithm?

Comment: The BlockSize property (inherited from the SymmetricAlgorithm base class) tells you the current block size in bits for the algorithm you're using. Divide that by 8 for the number of bytes.